# export table content to xlsx file

Tags: php, excel

I am allowing user to allow uploading xlsx file, performing transliteration (arabic to english) and displaying on web page as a table content. (same view as xlsx file).

1. Can I export table content to xlsx? (cell content should persist their cell position)
2. Or is it possible to write each processes cell result to xlsx?

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";
    require '../../Arabic.php';
    $Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Transliteration');
    $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
    echo '<h1>Parsing Result</h1>';
    echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse">';
    $eng = array();
    list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();  
    foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
//      if ($k == 0) continue; // skip first row
        echo '<tr>';
        for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
        {   
            $temp =  $Arabic->ar2en($r[$i]);    
            echo '<td>'.( (isset($r[$i])) ? $temp : '&nbsp;' ).'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
<h1>Upload</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
*.XLSX <input type="file" name="file"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Parse" />
</form>
```

Comment: How about returning a CSV which would be a lot simpler.

Comment: There are many ways to export HTML table data to xlsx, search google and you will find many tutorials/premade functions. I personally use a jQuery solution for this.

Comment: Use fputcsv to create a CSV file - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Why not use the PHPExcel library that you mentioned earlier that can both read __and__ write Excel files: SimpleXLSX can only __read__, it cannot write

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: not an issue, but at the end I want to display output file same as input

Comment: @MarkBaker: Yes, SimpleXLSX I am willing to use. But I tried even but there are so many example file, I could not find which I can use for read and write

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library. It is a very complex library for working with Excel documents and you should be able to achieve what you're trying to. I don't know about direct export of html tables, but it should be easy to write a simple method atod this library which will do the conversion.